# How to create a folder to save output in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, directory, psql

If I'd like to save the output from file1.sql to a new file file2.sql, I would use this command in terminal/cmd:

```
psql -U postgres -f file1.sql -o file2.sql
```

What if, though, I want file2.sql to be in a different folder?

If I try this command:

```
psql -U postgres -f file1.sql -o New/file2.sql,
```

that won't automatically make a new folder and will give an error. The New folder needs to exist before I can do this.

I need to this over many output files and many new folders. One obvious alternative would be to pre-create the required folders using Python, but really, is there no way Postgresql can create folders for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mkdir -p`.

It will try to create a directory `New` if it doesn't exist or does nothing if it already exists.The `&&` ensures that
your psql command runs only if the `mkdir` command succeeds.

```
mkdir -p New && psql -U postgres -f file1.sql -o New/file2.sql
```

If you want to run os commands inside  `psql`, simply use `\! <command>` option within `file1.sql` and then output via `\o` option.

```
\! mkdir -p New
\o New/file2.sql
```

Comment: Thanks. For Windows, it seems to work without the -p flag, though.